# How can i set textord_equation_detect true in TessBaseApi in Android

Tags: java, android, tesseract, tess-two

I added tess-two library in build.gradle like below

```
        implementation 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:9.1.0'
```

and I want to recognize mathematical expression,symbol with TessBaseApi() so i need set true textord_equation_detect but i don't know how to do this.The code I wrote using TessBaseApi is as follows

```
    public static boolean init(AssetManager assetManager){
    mTess = new TessBaseAPI();
    String datapath = CommonUtils.APP_PATH;
    File dir =new File(datapath + "tessdata/");
    if(!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdir();
        try {
            InputStream inStream = assetManager.open("CSDL/eng.traineddata");

            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(datapath + "tessdata/eng.traineddata");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int readCount = 0;
            while (((readCount = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1)) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, readCount);

            }
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    mTess.init(datapath,"eng");
    return true;
}
```

How can i set true textord_equation_detect? Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

`mTess.SetVariable("textord_equation_detect", "T");`

following examples in
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/2204

Comment: I tried in this way.But there was no difference.Still don't recognize math symbols,equations.I don't know what to do

Comment: This flag gets you equation detection but not OCR of the equation-containing regions. You just get the identification of where the equations are. So I believe this answer is correct as-is.